# Always use latest version of nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

Is their a way to automatically get the latest nuget package from a feed using the packages.config? For example:

In my packages config I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MyOwn.ApiProxy" version="17.2.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.1.4000" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

In this packages.config, the version for MyOwn.ApiProxy is specified as version `17.2.1.3`, but version `17.2.1.4` is already in the (private) nuget feed. How can I automatically update my packages.config to get the latetst version of my package? Should I create a pre-build task, or is there someway to specify `latest` in the version?

Using Visual Studio 2015 + NuGet server 2.11.2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From Nuget v2.8, the following attribute is supported in nuget.config.

```
<configuration>
<config> 
    <add key="dependencyversion" value="Highest" /> 
</config>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.8

Comment: By adding this configuration settings, the initial installation of the nuget package will indeed get the latest version, yet it will also write a line inside the packages.config with a specific version. This means that when the package in the feed is updated to, for example, `17.2.1.5` it will not update my packages.config and still use the old version. Can I do something like `<package id="MyOwn.ApiProxy" version="Highest" targetFramework="net452" />` aswell?

Comment: No, it wont work. Hope restore packages will helps you.